# plural nouns which is most correct - human resources services or human resource services

Tags: nouns

Which is most correct for use in signage to indicate the location of that department.

- Human resources services
- Human resource services

My understanding is that both could be correct however I am not aware of any rules that may indicate otherwise.

Comment: Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered.

Comment: (Neither is a "sentence".)

Comment: As you can see on the linked [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=human+resources+services%2C+human+resource+services&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chuman%20resources%20services%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chuman%20resource%20services%3B%2Cc0), both of them are almost equally used. It depends on context as Hot Licks mentioned. Unless you edit your question, your question could be closed. Just a heads-up.

Comment: Go leading edge.  Try something more personal, like "Personnel Services".

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed combinations blur the traditional line between compound nouns and compound adjectives, and while 'human resource services' does peak on [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=human%20resources%20services%2Chuman%20resource%20services&year_start=1900&year_end=2016&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chuman%20resources%20services%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chuman%20resource%20services%3B%2Cc0) at 0.0000004244% in 2006, a [wildcard search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=human%20resources%20*%2C%20human%20resource%20*&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Chuman%20resources%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhuman%20resources%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhuman%20resources%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhuman%20resources%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhuman%20resources%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhuman%20resources%20management%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhuman%20resources%20development%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhuman%20resources%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhuman%20resources%20department%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhuman%20resources%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhuman%20resources%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Chuman%20resource%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhuman%20resource%20management%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhuman%20resource%20development%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhuman%20resource%20planning%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhuman%20resource%20managers%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhuman%20resource%20department%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhuman%20resource%20practices%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhuman%20resource%20policies%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhuman%20resource%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhuman%20resource%20accounting%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhuman%20resource%20professionals%3B%2Cc0) for words that most commonly follow 'human resource' and 'human resources' might be more telling:

[image: human resource *, human resources *]

If you opt for 'human resources services' you have a three-word, eight-syllable compound noun (verboten when I was in school), which in turn violates the standard for such compounds by producing something akin to 'teethbrush'.  On the other hand, if you opt for 'Human resource services' but fail to hyphenate the first two words, you violate the standard treatment of compound adjectives preceding a noun, although at least you respect the avoidance of plural adjectives here that are not possessive, quantifying or demonstrative.

> If simply using '**Human Resources**' doesn't appeal to you, perhaps
>   the top-ten results depicted above will suggest a suitable
>   alternative.